# Child of scrollable, position: fixed element always returns 0 for positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a left-nav that is position fixed. I have a list of child elements in it and want to get the position of those elements relative to either the containing element or the viewport. Really anything.

However, when I call `getBoundingClientRect` I get 0,0,0,0 and when I call anything like offsetTop, scrollTop, clientTop, I get 0 as well for that.

When using jquery, calling `position().top` returns `-5`. It returns these values no matter how far down I am scrolled in the left-nav. I've also tried jQuery .offset() with no luck.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Please include enough code to replicate the issue ... css .. and html

Comment: Nevermind. According to this plunkr I made, apparently theres something else horribly wrong with my code. https://plnkr.co/edit/5hfiNLSA1kWnZcuV1pbu?p=preview

Comment: works now,eh? Thanks for the post, never heard of plnkr before, looks very useful.